# Linkedin API to retrieve company details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

I have gone through Linkedin gem(https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin). It works fine when I tried to access the public profiles. say for example( http://www.linkedin.com/pub/dinesh-ramasamy/19/a3a/922 )

But I could not access company profiles like CTs, TCS or whatever. say for example(http://www.linkedin.com/company/1680 )

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

After you've authenticated the client you can use the following to get all of the company fields based on the company_id from linkedin.  You can also use the linkedin universal-name to request company information instead of using the id.

company_data = client.company(:id => company_id, :fields=>["universal-name","email-domains","company-type","ticker","website-url","industries","status","logo-url","square-logo-url","blog-rss-url","twitter-id","employee-count-range","specialties","locations","description","stock-exchange","founded-year","end-year","num-followers"])